# Is it possible to mount VHDX in Linux as RW?

Tags: linux, storage, mount, vhdx

Is it possible to mount VHDX (not vhd) disk file in Linux as a read + write block device ?

I have found that qemu-img allows conversion of vhdx disks to other formats, but I am looking for read + write mounting of such disks.

There is also qemu-nbd which allows for read-only mounting of vhdx disks.

But is there a ways to mount vhdx disk as a read + write ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qemu-nbd` offers according to its man page `man qemu-nbd` a read only option. There is no indication for limitation on mount options.

`qemu-nbd` maps the vhdx file to a block device, e.g `/dev/nbd0`, which can then be mounted as `rw` to a directory.

This Gist from allenyllee contains mount/unmount scripts with the required commands:
https://gist.github.com/allenyllee/0a4c02952bf695470860b27369bbb60d

Comment: it needs to be verified then, off I go. Thank you for the link.

Comment: it works ! I was staring at the answer for days now not seeing it, just assuming that qemu-nbd only provide read-only functionality. Thank you.